# jquery append table under existing table and link to id of that rowrecord

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I am trying to take a table with some results in in and append it to another table row on a button click served by AJAX Jquery.
The function code currently is:

```
function options(id){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
      action: 'options_function',
      cid : id
    },      
    success: function (data) {
    var parentEl = jQuery('#list-table').parent();
    jQuery('#list-table').append('#ideal_option').html(data).show();.show();
    }
  });   
}
```

`#list-table` has a number of rows in it each with a button then when clicked fires the options function.

On success of that function is when I want to append the additional tables results `#ideal_option`. I want to make sure that the `#ideal-option` is being appended to the row I clicked the button in, not at the end of the `#list-table` table.

The above replaces the initial table with the new table instead of appending it. It is also not paired to the row it should be with.

How do I change this and make it right?

**FULL TABLE CODE WITH HTML**strong text****

```
echo "<table id ='ideal_option'>";  

foreach($check_availability as $available){ 
    $id=$available->id;
    $foh_nmbr=$available->FOH_Number;
    $tl_type=$available->Type;
    $sf_name=$available->Staff_First_Name;
    $sl_name=$available->Staff_Last_Name;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $foh_nmbr . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $tl_type . '</td>';
    echo("<td><select>");
foreach($Staff_On_Duty as $person){         
    $sf_name_option=$person->Staff_First_Name; 
    $sl_name_option=$person->Staff_Last_Name;
    echo("<option value = $sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option");
    if (($sf_name_option == $sf_name) && ($sl_name_option == $sl_name)) echo (" selected");
    echo(">$sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option</option>"); 
}
echo("</select></td>");
    
    echo '<td>' . "<button id='party' class='button ' onclick='party($id, $cid)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button>" . '</td>'; 
echo '</tr>';}
echo '</table>';
```

HTML for initial table

```
<table width='100%' border='0' style='display:inline-table' id='list-header' class='list-table-header'>     <th>Name</th>           <th>Email Address</th>      <th>Time Stamp</th>     <th>Status</th>     <th>Wait</th>       <th>Action</th> <th>Notify</th>     <tbody id='list-table'>     </tbody>
```

Comment: I suspect that there is some non-unique ids in there... Can you post the HTML?

Comment: added to the initial post

Answer (score 0):

First part, it doesn't appear that `ideal_option` is specified anywhere in the markup, so I'm guessing it's somewhere else and hidden by default.  In that case, your chaining may be wrong.

```
jQuery('#list-table').append('#ideal_option').html(data).show();
```

should be

```
jQuery('#list-table').append( jQuery('#ideal_option').html(data) ).show();
```

Second part, targeting the row where you clicked, you'll need to handle the click event as well as the data to be sent.  I'd suggest using jQuery's bindings to handle this instead of a raw `onclick`, passing the parameters via data attributes:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','button.button',function party(e){
  var t = e.currentTarget; // this represents the button
  var id = jQuery(t).data('id'); // get data from the button
  var cid = jQuery(t).data('cid');
  jQuery(t).closest('td').append('You clicked here with id '+ id +' and cid '+ cid);
  options(id, cid, t); // we could pass in the target or the event here
});
```

I've very likely misunderstood the relationships in your JS functions, but
[Here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7au2jp1k/2/) with an approximation of (1) appending data to the **end** of the table, and (2) targeting the `<td>` of the clicked button.

Comment: Hi thanks so much. SO in keeping troubleshooting practices, I just moved over the first part of the jQuery('#list-table').append( jQuery('#ideal_option').html(data) ).show(); but it didnt do anything and I am not sure why. I checked a couple of times against the example and actually copied and pasted it in. Nothing. Previously I could get it to append, but it would replace the data. The ideal_option is the table in the HTML code. Depending on when you opened this, I added that about an hour ago to the post when I realized I didnt before

Comment: ok so I have the actual data now coming through ok. I used something more simple - jQuery('tbody#list-table').append(data);. For some reason I couldnt get the first example to work but I appreciate it. However, in using your second example, I cant get that working either.  I am getting unidentified errors on CID and Id, which are the same btw